# Export Only Child grid to excel from Ajax Update Panel

Tags: c#

I have an Ajax update panel, contains Parent grid and child grid. I want to export only child grid on a button click.

Any guidance in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Which child grid do you want to export? Do you have an export-button in every row of the parent-grid? A little bit more context would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have:

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel HeaderText="Trigger History" runat="server" Width="100%">                                                                    
                        <ContentTemplate> 
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvSurgeDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                ShowFooter="true" Width="1000px"
                                OnRowDataBound="gvSurgeDetails_OnRowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging ="gvSurgeDetails_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging ="true" PageIndex="0" PagerSettings-Mode="Numeric" PagerSettings-PageButtonCount="10" PagerSettings-FirstPageText="First" PagerSettings-LastPageText ="Last">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("id") %>');">
                                                <img id='imgdiv<%# Eval("SurgeLevelUpdateID") %>' width="9px" border="0"
                                                    src="Images/plus.gif" alt="" /></a>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle Width="20px" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update ID">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblUpdateID" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,
                                                                    "UpdateID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdateDate" HeaderText="Updated At" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="By" HeaderText="Updated By" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Color" HeaderText="Colour" />                                    
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Confirmation" HeaderText="CONFIRMATION" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="100%">                                                    
                                                    <div id='div<%# Eval("UpdateID") %>' style="overflow: auto; display: none; position: relative; left: 15px; overflow: auto">
                                                        <asp:GridView ID="gv_Child" runat="server" Width="98%"
                                                            AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
                                                            <Columns>                                                                
                                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="Value" />                                                                
                                                            </Columns>                                                               
                                                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4D92C1" ForeColor="White" />                                                           
                                                        </asp:GridView>
                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="gvChild_Export" OnClick="gvChild_Export_Click" runat="server" Text ="Export" CausesValidation="False" />

                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0063A6" ForeColor="White" />

                            </asp:GridView>

                        </ContentTemplate> 

                    </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
```

I want to export 'gv_child' on click of 'gvchild_export'.